# Does Kong support 'state' validation during OAuth authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, kong

We are implementing Kong as a gateway and we will be using OAuth for authentication and authorization.

I could not find anything in Kong's OAuth docs that mention what kind of validations it can perform on the request.

Specifically about the client passing the 'state' parameter to the /authorization endpoint.
Would Kong be storing that in it's session and later verifying it when we get the response from the OAuth server?